# type or namespace could not be found

Tags: windows, mobile

hello i am doing windows 7 mobile application on Framework 4.
while creating object for class IPEndPoint giving error that type or namespace could not be found.please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `using System.Net` at the top of your file to include the namespace. However, it's possible, that the class isn't in the win 7 mobile framework. You probably are out of luck then.

Answer (score 0):

do you have

```
using System.Net;
```

in the top of the class that uses IPEndPoint?

Comment: public class Configuration
    {
        public static Configuration _Singleton;
        public static Configuration Instance { get { return _Singleton; } }

        static
        Configuration()
        {
            _Singleton = new Configuration();
        }
        

        public IPEndPoint Endpoint { get; private set; }
        public string WcfRoot { get; private set; }
        public string SipUser { get; private set; }
        public string Password { get; private set; }
        public string ClientId { get; private set; }
        public string SipEtag { get; private set; }

Comment: @Naresh: We understand that you have an error. Please do not nag.